# Why won't Vuex getter work in this simple code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to create a JSFiddle so that I can experiment with a problem I am facing in my real app and then hopefully show that JSFiddle to others. The code is below and I am getting an error stating

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

what am I doing wrong?

```js
Vue.component('product-info', {
  template: '<div> {{Product[0].ProductTitle}} </div>',
  computed: {

    Product() { return this.$store.getters.getProduct},

  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.Product.length) {
      this.getProduct();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getProduct() {
      return this.$store.dispatch('loadProduct')
    }
  }
});

let ProductData = [{
  "ProductID": 101,
  "ProductTypeID": 1,
  "ProductTitle": "Sony PS4 Pro with Death Standing",
  "ProductDescription": "<p>Grab yourself a new console complete with a top title with the Sony PlayStation 4 Pro & Death Stranding Bundle</p>\n  <p>Experience the most spectacular graphics on every game and film with the PlayStation 4 Pro – with 4K Ultra HD resolution and HDR compatibility.  Twice the power as previous models, the PlayStation 4 Pro achieves faster and more stable frame rates as well as incredibly lifelike details.</p>"
}];

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    Product: []
  },
  actions: {
    loadProduct({
      commit
    }) {
      commit('setProduct', ProductData)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getProduct: (state) => state.Product
  },
  mutations: {
    setProduct(state, ProductData) {
      state.Product = ProductData
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <product-info></product-info>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed it to `return` it from your computed variable and in your `template` check for `length` of product before printing it.

```
<div v-if="Product.length">
```

```js
Vue.component('product-info', {
  template: '<div v-if="Product.length"> {{Product[0].ProductTitle}} </div>',
  computed: {
    Product() { return this.$store.getters.getProduct},

  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.Product.length) {
      this.getProduct();
    }

    // you need to right some promise to get value from length in your `axios`, eg:
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('product length:', this.Product.length)}, 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    getProduct() {
      return this.$store.dispatch('loadProduct')
    }
  }
});

let ProductData = [{
  "ProductID": 101,
  "ProductTypeID": 1,
  "ProductTitle": "Sony PS4 Pro with Death Standing",
  "ProductDescription": "<p>Grab yourself a new console complete with a top title with the Sony PlayStation 4 Pro & Death Stranding Bundle</p>\n  <p>Experience the most spectacular graphics on every game and film with the PlayStation 4 Pro – with 4K Ultra HD resolution and HDR compatibility.  Twice the power as previous models, the PlayStation 4 Pro achieves faster and more stable frame rates as well as incredibly lifelike details.</p>"
}];

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    Product: []
  },
  actions: {
    loadProduct({
      commit
    }) {
      commit('setProduct', ProductData)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getProduct: (state) => state.Product
  },
  mutations: {
    // you need to write your sxios promise here
    setProduct(state, ProductData) {
      state.Product = ProductData
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app">
  <product-info></product-info>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer actually solved the cause of my problem. I was missing the `<div v-if="Product.length"> {{Product[0].ProductTitle}} </div>`. Without that I was getting errors that Product[0].ProductTitle was undefined. Why do I have to check `length` in the template when I'm already checking in the `mounted()` hook?

Comment: @volumeone, because HTML markup will be waiting first to render on the screen, so we need to use `v-if` to hide the vue syntax getting render to the screen and cause the error while the data is not available.

Comment: it also works if I do `v-for item in Product` loop without checking length first. is that because `v-for` automatically checks length?

Comment: @volumeone no, that’s because it loops through the items in the array and the array is empty at first

Comment: @lukaszmtw so it keeps looping no matter what? that is, the array is empty so is that not also an `undefined` error? if the array finally gets some data does it loop through it again?

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the computed property as a function:

```js
computed: {

    Product() { return this.$store.getters.getProduct }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited it and now get another error saying `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Is that because `Product` is now a method and not a property? How could I make it a data property?

Comment: @volumeone you've omitted the `return`. Check this answer again

Comment: Yes, you’re missing the `return`.